# How (in GEDCOM) to document returning to a home previously immigrated to?

Tags: immigration

Person went from France to Canada in the 1800s but in 1914 he passed through New York from "Besaçes, Roanne, France" via Le Havre with destination listed as "home, (illegible), Canada."

Would we treat this as another IMMIgration event?

Answer (score 2):

I use a custom event for Travelled rather than an Immigration or Emigration event, as I have lots of instances of people travelling back and forth (e.g. emigrating to Canada but returning several times to visit their family in England).

Comment: I’ve always had a tendency to stick to the GEDCOM 5.5.1 specification, but since I don’t have to worry about transferring my data, this is worth considering.

Comment: In fact, one could make an argument for having EMIG and IMMI combined as a single event, with a from/to date.

Comment: @WGroleau That wouldn't cater for one way trips or multi-stage ones (I have a set of Travelled events that go from England to India to Palestine (1940s) to Egypt to Sudan to Italy to England again -- the travels of a war time soldier.)

Comment: Could you edit in an example showing what sub records you use?

Comment: @WGroleau What do you mean by sub-record?

Comment: Each line of a GEDCOM file beginning with the number N starts a sub-record of the nearest preceding record that starts with N-1, and ends with the next N-1.

Comment: @WGroleau It would be specific to the software product i use which includes a non-standard extension to the IMMI and EMIG events to include 2 places -- place and place (to) and a mechanism inn the UI to display 'Travelled' instead of 'Emigrated' -- if you use the same software (Family Historian) it might be useful, but your question is software agnostic.

Comment: What does it look like in GEDCOM if you export?  Does it have other fields in addition to from/to?

Comment: @WGroleau It has all the standard fields for an Event, the IMMI tag, plus a custom 2 _PLAC for the second place.

Answer (score 1):

I would treat it as another immigration event BUT like everything in genealogy there is no right or wrong way to record events / facts, the key thing is to be consistent. I presume you have asked the question as you don't know when they went to France?

This is what the gedcom definition of the immigration tag is:

> Information about an individual with respect to a specific event, such as the age, marital status, religious affiliation of this individual at time of this event. Keep in mind that this is data specific to the individual owning this event and not the data that belongs to the source in which this data was found. For instance Immigration and Emigration events should use a reference a source structure to show the SHIP and PORT information concerning the event. Roles of other individuals can be shown using the EVENt record. A link to the event record can be made by using the SOURce structure to point to the EVENt record. The event record in this case would be an evidence record supporting the assertions made in creating this event structure.

Comment: Where did you find that quote?  It’s not in the 5.5.1 specification.

Comment: I am a big fan of consistency, but the fact is that humans are not consistent.  Every program I have ever used has required I shoehorn facts and events into formats that just don’t fit.  The most flexibility I ever found was editing raw GEDCOM, but even that won’t support the full range of human behavior.  But as a software engineer, I understand that this will ALWAYS be the case with software.

Comment: It is at http://user.it.uu.se/~andersa/gedcom/ch2.html

Comment: Must be an older version.  I might get some ideas from it, but I mainly work with version 5.5.1

Comment: The 5.5.1 spec says 

"IMMI {IMMIGRATION}:= An event of entering into a new locality with the intent of residing there." So this fits with your original question.

Comment: I'd hesitate to call it a "new" locality when it is his home that he is returning to..